# Python: Evaluating multivariate normal distribution at the same point but different means and standard deviations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I tried using `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal()` to evaluate the pdf at a point x for different values of the mean and of the standard deviation. However, it doesn't broadcast.

#### Minimal Working Example

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# A single x where I want to evaluate it at
x = np.array([1.0])
# Multiple means where I want to evaluate the PDF at
means = np.array([1.0, 10.0])
standard_deviations = np.array([1.0, 2.0])

# If I use the stats function, it evaluates only at one point
stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(x=x, mean=means, cov=np.diag(means**2))
```

Comment: which version of SciPy do you use? Because the above generates:
`TypeError: pdf() got an unexpected keyword argument 'means'`

Comment: You are specifying just one multivariate normal distribution. Do you want to evaluate pdf of x with two different normal distributions?

Comment: @FBruzzesi Basically I have a point `x=np.array([1.0])` and I want to evaluate a large number of univariate normal distributions on it. These distributions are specified by means and variances which I have stored in a vector of means and a vector of standard deviations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question title says "multivariate normal", but the code shows a univariate input for `x`, and in a comment you say "...  I want to evaluate a large number of univariate normal distributions...".

To evaluate different univariate normal distributions at a single point, use `scipy.stats.norm`, and pass arrays as the parameters. The `pdf` method handles broadcasting of the inputs.

For example,

```
In [1]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [2]: x = np.array([1.0])

In [3]: means = np.array([1.0, 10.0])

In [4]: standard_deviations = np.array([1.0, 2.0])

In [5]: norm.pdf(x, means, standard_deviations)
Out[5]: array([3.98942280e-01, 7.99187055e-06])
```

Comment: Can you add an answer for multivariate normal? I know OP didn't show such a use case, but I found this post through the term "multivariate normal" and I would like the answer